# I have the B1B2 visa but can only stay for 90 days

Tags: international-travel

I just got to the US, normally I use my ESTA but this time I asked and was granted the B1B2 visa. When I got to the airport in customs the officer was chatting with me, didn't stamp my passport. So I got home went to see my I 94 and says I can only stay the 90. What can I do to stay the 6 months? I do have the B1 B2 visa but it's like the officer didn't count it or saw it. What can I do

Comment: When you got the visa, did you explain what your travel plans were and why you needed to stay six months? Did you explain to the officer at the border?

Comment: I did not, he didn't ask. I thought I would automatically have the 6 months regardless of the time I want to stay.